# Horizontal lines not appearing on matplotlib plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is the sample data:

```
                 Datetime   Price  Data1  Data2  ShiftedPrice
0 2017-11-05 09:20:01.134  2123.0  12.23  34.12         300.0
1 2017-11-05 09:20:01.789  2133.0  32.43  45.62         330.0
2 2017-11-05 09:20:02.238  2423.0  35.43  55.62           NaN
3 2017-11-05 09:20:02.567  3423.0  65.43  56.62           NaN
4 2017-11-05 09:20:02.948  2463.0  45.43  58.62           NaN
```

I am trying to draw a plot between Datetime and Shiftedprice columns and horizontal lines for mean, confidence intervals of the ShiftedPrice column.
Have a look at the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np

df1 = df.dropna(subset=['ShiftedPrice'])
df1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax = df1.plot(x='Datetime',y='ShiftedPrice')

# Plotting the mean
ax.axhline(y=df1['ShiftedPrice'].mean(), color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
plt.show()

# Plotting Confidence Intervals
ax.axhline(y=df1['ShiftedPrice'].mean() + 1.96*np.std(df1['ShiftedPrice'],ddof=1), color='g', linestyle=':', lw=2)
ax.axhline(y=df1['ShiftedPrice'].mean() - 1.96*np.std(df1['ShiftedPrice'],ddof=1), color='g', linestyle=':', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

My problem is that horizontal lines are not appearing. Instead, I get the following message

```
ax.axhline(y=df1['ShiftedPrice'].mean(), color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
Out[22]: <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xccc5c18>
```

Comment: Hi David, it is not working yet

Comment: Apparently you run part of your code in different cells. `plt.show()` will only work for the output of a single cell. However you seem to use the `inline` backend. Hence you can show your figure again by stating the figure name `fig` in any subsequent cell.

Comment: with the `%matplotlib inline` backend, you shouldn't need any calls to `plt.show`. Also, like Ernest mentions, make sure you run all of this in a single cell.